# Reducing the file size of MATLAB variables

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

**Process of extracting data,**

I am analyzing 4000 to 8000 DICOM files using matlab codes. DICOM files are read using `dicomread()` function. Each DICOM file contains 932*128 photon count data coming from 7 detectors. While reading DICOM files, I convert data into double and stored in 7 `cell array` variables (from seven detectors). So each cell contains 128*128 photon counting data and cell array contain 4000 to 8000 cells.

**Question.**

When I save each variable separately, size of each variable is 3GB. So for 7 variables it will be 21GB, Saving them and reading back takes awful lot of time. (RAM of my computer is 4GB)
Is there a way to reduce the size of variable?

Thanks.

Comment: First you said 932*128, then 128*128, what size is the right one? Because 932*128*(8*7*5000) ~ 30 GB, while 128*128*(8*7*5000) ~ 4GB.

Comment: @ZizyArcher, each DICOM files have 932*128 data, that is form 7 detectors. But I extracted data form the DICOM file to blocks of 128 * 128, and created 7 variables so each variable has data form one detector!

Comment: I see, but 932/7 ~ 133, not 128. Anyway, the final size should be ~ 4GB. I created 1x4000 cell array filled with 128x128 random doubles, leading to 500 MB data size (saving and loading is still quite slow). Not sure how come your files are 3GB each.

Comment: What content does your data have? Is it all integers? Does it contain a lot of zeros?

Comment: @SardarUsama , There are some zeros produced by dead pixels and number always remains below 10,000 and they are whole numbers.

Comment: @ZizyArcher, There are some dead pixel columns which I avoided when converting unit16 data into double

Comment: @E_net4,techraf,Gert Arnold, What part of the question required more detail, and I cant understand why downvote

Comment: That comment will not notify the users that you mentioned, I only happen to have passed by. This question lacks severely in details: there is no code for reproducing the problem, not enough information about the nature of the DICOM files (they can have a wide variety of encodings), no explanation regarding what you intend to do with them, and no attempt at solving the problem yourself. Without these, potential answers are less likely to be useful to future visitors. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different data type will help. You can save data as float instead of double, as DICOM files have it as float too (from http://northstar-www.dartmouth.edu/doc/idl/html_6.2/DICOM_Attributes.html; Graphic Data). This halves size at no loss. You might want to expand to double when doing operations on data to avoid inaccuracies creeping up.
Additional compression by saving it as uint16 (additional x2 space saving) or even uint8 (x4) might be possible, but I would be wary of this - it might work great in all test cases but make problems when you least expect it.

Cell array is not problematic in terms of speed or size - you will not gain (much) by switching to something else. Your data gobbles up memory, not the cell array itself. If you wish, you can save data in a 128x128x7x8000 float array - it should work just fine too.
But if the number of images (this 4000-8000) can increase at any point, rescaling the array will be a pretty costly operation in terms of space and time. Cell arrays are much easier to extend - 8k values to move around instead of 8k*115k=900M values.

Another option is to separate data in chunks. You probably don't need to be working on all 4000 images at once. You can load 500 images, finish your work on them, move on to next 500 images etc. Batch size obviously depends on your hardware and what processing you do with data, but I guess about 500 could be a pretty reasonable starting point.